# angular ui-grid row selection.on

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

Every example I try to follow gives me the same error. I want to click on a row and have it route to a page with that data. But I can't even get the row click to register.

My stripped down controller:

```
var CanadaApp = angular.module('CanadaApp', [ "ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.grid", "ui.grid.selection" ]);

CanadaApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'dataService', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, dataService,  uiGridConstants) {

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: false,
        enableRowSelection: true, 
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            $scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor( $scope.singleFilter, 200 );

            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
                var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
                $log.log(msg);
            });                
        },
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'name' },
            { field: 'population' },
        ]
    };        
}]);
```

No matter what docs I read or examples I follow, I get

```
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined**
```

at line:

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged
```

Frankly, I don't get why it's assigning gridApi to $scope.gridApi then changing grid Api, but that's what the examples show over and over:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EO920wsxuqr3YU8931GF?p=preview

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/205_row_editable

(I actually plan to route to another page based on row id, so that's another ball of wax.)

Comment: use `cellTemplate` property inside `colDefs` objects to make a column clickable.

Comment: What about clicking a row though?

Answer (score 0):

the error went away for me after I registered `ui.grid.selection` in `app.js`